# Smarty3 escape not working with json

Tags: php, json, escaping, smarty, prestashop

I am using Prestashop 1.6.1.4 and all seem to be working fine except escaping json returned data from ajax call.

Using blocklayered navigation giving error 500 when trying to render/escape json data from server to product-list.tpl.

Regular pages which use the same file (product-list.tpl) working just fine.

The error I am getting is:

> Undefined index: escape in
>   **/home/xxx/public_html/cache/smarty/compile/e4/a1/fd/e4a1fd2f5285aae65055ce86ad9af69b31b94166.file.product-list.tpl.php**
>   on line **95**
>  
>  **Fatal error**:  Call to a member
>   function escape() on a non-object in
>   **/home/xxx/public_html/cache/smarty/compile/e4/a1/fd/e4a1fd2f5285aae65055ce86ad9af69b31b94166.file.product-list.tpl.php**
>   on line **95**

This is a brand new server and at the beginning I had also an issue when trying to truncate chars so I had to install mbstring thru EasyApache 3 and everything was fixed.

My guess is that I am missing some mod/extension/plugin for Apache or PHP.

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Can you download this compiled file and check what `php` code is there on line 95?

Comment: This is what I have on line 95:
<a class="product_img_link" href="<?php echo $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_MODIFIER]['escape'][0][0]->escape($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['product']->value['link'],'html','UTF-8');?>
@Indre

Answer (score 0):

It end up being a mod_security issue.
I disabled Apache mod_security and now everything works.

Thank you very much